# Why might an iOS app crash inside _deselectAllNonMultiSelectRowsAnimated:notifyDelegate:?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iOS app that crashes (bad access) when I pop a view controller from the navigation stack.  The deeper controller has a table view, and during `viewWillAppear`, I can see from the stack trace that it's calling an internal method called `_deselectAllNonMultiSelectRowsAnimated:notifyDelegate:`.  Does anyone know what goes on inside this method?  Specifically, is it expected that my implementation of `tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` isn't getting called?

Comment: You should figure out what the garbage object is. Perhaps run with `NSZombieEnabled` on, or enable malloc stack logging.

Comment: Thanks.  NSZombieEnabled didn't help much, but I'll give malloc stack logging a go.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but it looks like the _dselectAllNonMultiSelectRowsAnimated:notifyDelegate: is just doing some clean up while also anouncing a notification.  With out seeing your code it is a little hard to say why this would be vomiting.  A little more detail and we may be able to help.

Comment: Understood.  Hard to know which bits to post though.  Thanks anyway.